# Server Sent Events - NestJS and ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, jwt, nestjs, server-sent-events

I'm having a problem using NestJS, Server Sent Events, JWT and React. That's the scenario:

- I have a NestJS written API that's using a JWT Authentication strategy. I'll call it API **A**
- I have a second API that I have no control over. I'll call it API **B**.
- I have a frontend written in ReactJS, using NextJS.
- The API **B** monitors a system that links some resources to different users. That's not the case, but imagine a system that monitors several servers that belongs to different users. When a predefined event happen, for example a server goes down, the API "B" notifies the API **A** via a webhook.
- The API **A** then notifies the Frontend that a event happened

My problem is when something like this happens:

- User 1 owns a resource **X**. User 2 owns the resource **Y**. The API **B** sends, via webhook, the event. But both User 1 and 2 receives the notification.

How can I solve this problem?

Obs: I know this can be achieved using other technologies. Such as Websockets, a Queue or Polling the information. But I'd like to use SSE directly.

That's how I implemented:

**NestJS Controller code**

```
@UseGuards(AuthGuard)
@Sse('sse')
sse(@Request() req) {
    return this.monitoringServerService.sendEvents();
   }
}
```

**MonitoringServerService code**

```
@Injectable()
export class MonitoringService {      
  private events = new Subject<any>();
  addEvent(event) {
    this.events.next(event);
  }

  sendEvents() {
    return this.events.asObservable();
  }
}
```